# Expected value property concerning two random variables

Tags: random-variables, expected-value

Given two bounded real-valued random variables $X, Y$, is it necessarily the case that
$$\mathbb{E}_{x,y \sim (X, Y)} [(x + y)^2] \ge \mathbb{E}_{x, y \sim (X, Y)} [(\mathbb{E}[X \mid y] + \mathbb{E}[Y \mid x])^2]?$$

Comment: What is your unusual notation meant to convey?

Comment: Each side is an expectation over the joint distribution of X, Y. E[X|y] is the expectation of X conditioned on Y = y.

Comment: I think you are asking if $E[(X+Y)^2] \geq E[(E[X|Y] + E[Y|X])^2]$.

Comment: Yeah -- I figured it would be clearer if I clarified what I'm taking each expectation over, but maybe not.

Comment: @Michael I think that's a bit imprecise, since the right side has two different copies of $X$ and $Y$ happening. I guess I'd notate it $E[(E[X'|Y] + E[Y'|X])^2]$ where $X'$ is an independent draw of $X$ conditioned on $Y$ and $Y'$ is an independent draw of $Y$ conditioned on $X$.

Comment: @usul : Some people prefer to replace $E[X]$ and $E[Y]$ with $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$, some people prefer to replace $E[X|Y]$ and $E[Y|X]$ with $h(Y)$ and $g(X)$ for some particular functions that are versions of the conditional expectation.  The concept of $X'$ being an "independent draw of $X$ conditioned on $Y$" is not precise as $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $Y:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ were presumably well defined random variables, $E[Y|X]$ and $E[X|Y]$ have standard definitions, and it is not clear what $X'$ is and if the probability space even supports any independent draws.

Comment: @Michael, okay, but it is equally unclear what $E[E[X|Y]]$ means when the outer expectation is already over $X,Y$.

Comment: For a given problem, there is typically only one probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$ and so $E[X]=E[E[X|Y]]$ is the way most mathematicians would write the "tower property."  I do see non-mathematicians, perhaps even some mathematicians, introducing additional subscripts, particularly when they have a complicated problem and they just want to remind the reader what is random.  So your notation is not wrong and you are consistent with what a lot of others do. The problem is that when you try to precisely interpret those subscripts it can lead to extra-probabilistic concepts that are nonstandard.

Comment: So you can define $W=E[X|Y]$ and $Z=E[Y|X]$ (with the understanding that these are "versions" of the conditional expectation) and then $E[W]$ and $E[Z]$ are standard expectations on the probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$. See for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation

Answer (score 2):

(Solution courtesy Holden Lee.)

We have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[((X - \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]) - (Y - \mathbb{E}[Y \mid X]))^2] &\ge 0\\
\mathbb{E}[(X - \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y])^2 + (Y - \mathbb{E}[Y \mid X])^2] &\ge 2 \mathbb{E}[(X - \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y])(Y - \mathbb{E}[Y \mid X])].
\end{align*}
Now, observe that
$$\mathbb{E}[(X - \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y])^2 = \mathbb{E}[X^2] + \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]^2] - 2\mathbb{E}[X \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]] = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]^2],$$
where in the last step we use the fact that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]] &= \mathbb{E}_{y \sim Y}[\mathbb{E}_{x \sim X \mid Y = y}[x \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y = y]]]\\
&= \mathbb{E}_y[\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y = y] \mathbb{E}_{x \sim X \mid Y = y}[x]] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]^2].
\end{align*}
Similarly we have that $\mathbb{E}[(Y - \mathbb{E}[Y \mid X])^2] = \mathbb{E}[Y^2] - \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X]^2]$. Additionally we have that
$$\mathbb{E}[X \mathbb{E}[Y \mid X]] = \mathbb{E}_x[x \mathbb{E}[Y \mid X = x]] = \mathbb{E}_x[\mathbb{E}[XY \mid X = x]] = \mathbb{E}[XY].$$

Together with these facts, we adapt out earlier equation:
$$\mathbb{E}[X^2] - \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]^2] + \mathbb{E}[Y^2] - \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X]^2] \ge 2 \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y] \mathbb{E}[Y \mid X]] - 2 \mathbb{E}[XY].$$
Rearranging terms:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X^2 + 2XY + Y^2] &\ge \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]^2] + 2 \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y] \mathbb{E}[Y \mid X] + \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X]^2]\\
\mathbb{E}[(X + Y)^2] &\ge \mathbb{E}[(\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y] + \mathbb{E}[Y \mid X])^2],
\end{align*}
as desired.